# How to crop image from camera preview view in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a camera view and top of that I placed one blue rectangle line imageview.

[image]

My Questions is, when I press the capture button I have to save the image whatever is inside the rectangle area. I tried with below mentioned code but it doesn't crop that area.

```
let cgImage = image.cgImage
let croppedCGImage: CGImage = cgImage!.cropping(to: self.m_TrimArea.frame)!
let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage)
```

Here self.m_TrimArea is an imageview which holds the blue rectangle line. Please give some guidance to achieve this.

Comment: I searched also a lot to do that - If you are willing to use a POD I can recommend to use -> https://github.com/ruslanskorb/RSKImageCropper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use the following pod. https://cocoapods.org/pods/Toucan